# Trying to code a support vector machine and i got this error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to write an SVM training it using a dataframe which i converted to a np.array. i keep getting this error. Any suggestions?

---

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-8f22a9c1d269> in <module>()
    114 
    115 classifier = SVM()
--> 116 classifier.train(fitdata = trainingdata[1:,8])
    117 classifier.visualize()
    118 

<ipython-input-22-8f22a9c1d269> in train(self, fitdata)
     32 
     33     for yi in self.fitdata:
---> 34         for featureset in self.fitdata[yi]:
     35             for feature in featureset:
     36                 alldata.append(feature)

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

​
```

Comment: Can you show us more of your code?

Answer (score 1):

I faced same error yesterday and that was because in fit parameter when it was trying to access label column which was not present there as data was in numpy array format but it was trying to access it by name like

```
  y_train[column_name]
```

which shouldn't be the case. As you have already told that your data is in numpy array format, make sure it is not accessing any data by column name.